# Googlebot request types

Tags: http-headers, web-crawler, tornado, googlebot, google-crawlers

Does Google's bot send HEAD requests as well as GET requests?

I wondering about this because I'm running a Tornado application that does not support HEAD request and I have *a lot* of 404 errors in Google Search Console.

To verify that the Tornado application is not accepting HEAD requests I do:

```
curl -I example.com/this-url-exists

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 08:49:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 7520
Connection: close
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
Server: TornadoServer/4.2.1
```

I suspect that the Googlebots are doing the same for some of the crawling.

Can this be right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is aimed at [professional webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: ok, I will put it there. thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off-topic on Stack Overflow, and has been cross-posted on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91103/googlebots-request-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Googlebot does not send HEAD requests (and neither do other major search engines' crawlers). But either way, this 404 is not caused by the fact that the request is a HEAD: sending HEAD to a resource that does not support it returns status code 405, not 404.

Comment: Is there an easy way to implement it across all resources? I presume, internally, that it does a GET request, checks the content length and just returns the header?

Comment: Yeah, if you put `def head(self, *a, **kw): return self.get(*a, **kw)`, in a common base class for all your handlers it should just work. I don't know why it doesn't do that by default, but hardly anyone seems to care about HEAD requests.